# Countdown while object position in certain range

Tags: android, loops, timer, while-loop, countdown

I'm trying to show a timer to the user that counts down from 3 to 0. This timer should be made visible when a user drags an object in a certain position and should be stopped (and resetted) when the user drags the object out of that position..

For now, I'm working with Log.d, the actual displaying of the timer, I'll deal with later.

So far, I've got (non-working code) :

```
 public void setX(float x) {
        isCheckOut = false;              
    // if basket is further than slotmargin 
     if (x + width/2 > SlotManager.SlotmarginX) {
        // if basket is NOT in CheckOut area    
         if (this.Y < MainGamePanel.height - 80 - height/2){
            x = SlotManager.SlotmarginX - width/2;

        } else {
            // if basket IS in CheckOut area
            x = MainGamePanel.width - width/2;
            isCheckOut = true;
            GameManager.CheckOut();
        }
        }

     this.X = x;
 }
```

And, in the GameManager :

```
public static void CheckOut() {

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
            while (basket.isCheckOut == true){

                for (int i=3;i>3;i--){
                    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                    Timer t = new Timer(); 
                    t.schedule(new TimerTask() { 
                            public void run() { 
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() { 
                                            public void run() { 
                                                Log.d("", "Countdown " + i);
                                            } 
                                    }); 
                            } 
                    }, 2000); 

                }

            }
      }
    });
    t.start();      
}
```

I feel like I'm getting somewhere, but can't wrap my head around the loop-timer combination. The timer should stop when the isCheckOut == false. Now, I'm thinking I start the timer over-and-over... AND I cannot use the int "i" to display the current countdown int, because it's not final?

Help is deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use this approach:

```
final int delayMillis = 1000;

final boolean count = true;

final Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        // your code

        if (count) // stop timer when count is false
        {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayMillis);
        }

    }
};
```

To start timer use:

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayMillis);
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it.. it works. How would I implement it so, that there is always only ONE runnable instance running? In my current implementation, I find that the runnable is ran 4 or 5 times because the object is entering the area. If I drag the object outside the area, I set count to false, stopping all 4 or 5 instances.. Would you have an advice on how to start just one?

Comment: Make a global boolean variable which will indicate if runnable is already running. Example: if(!isRunning){ //start new runnable, isRunning = true; when runnable do his job switch isRunning to false}

Comment: Woops.. ofcourse. Thanks. I can even use the count boolean. Duh.

Comment: Dmytro, thanks to your answer I was able to write https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=happyworx.nl.Applez . Thank you!